# removAllChildren function missing from mobileweb

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Environment:
Mac running Appcelerator Studio 4.4
SDK version: 5.1.1
Deploying to MobileWeb
Testing in Firefox

I am currently building a cross platform solution for android/iOS and mobileweb.  I am using a scrollview in one of my interfaces.

At one point in my code I am removing all the children from the scrollview using the removeAllChildren function.

This is working fine in both iOS and Android.  In mobile web, however, I find that the removeAllChildren function is not defined.  I can see a _removeAllChildren property but not the function.

The documentation says this function is supported for mobileweb, is there an issue here that anyone else has encountered?

If there is an issue, does anyone have a suitable work-around that they have used?

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the Appcelerator JIRA https://jira.appcelerator.org/. If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: This is the link to the ticket in Jira.  It seems that it is a known issue:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-12426?jql=text%20~%20%22removeallchildren%22

Answer (score 3):

I have looked in Jira and it is clear that the development team have not completed this functionality.  If you want to follow their progress you can go to the following:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-12426?jql=text%20~%20%22removeallchildren%22

I intend to remove the List and add it back again, rather than remove the actual children (as I think this will be faster when there are large numbers of children and I do not want to implement jQuery for just this one feature).

Answer (score 0):

appcelerator allows plug in jQuery.
Try this http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: This raises two questions:

How do I add jQuery as a plugin so that it only affects mobileweb and not iOS or Android?

How do I change the code so that my Appcelerator functionality utilises the jQuery Clear for mobile web while using removeAllChildren for iOS and Android?

Comment: when programming for mobile web with Titanium, its important to understand how that works with mobile libraries, like jQuery for instance. Anytime you are programming for MobileWeb in particular, you can use any web code you like, references to the DOM, standard browser objects etc. just make sure your putting that code within a block -- if(OS_MOBILEWEB) { ... my mobile web code .. }